# Why NOT to use GMail?

Tags: email, gmail, webmail

I've been a mutt user for years and I was skeptical when I came to know about gmail. After I started using it though, I started to see all the good stuff, mostly the ability to access my email with just a simple browser, the end of email backups and the spam filter.

I then tried to go back to a dedicated email client (even using my gmail account via IMAP), but fell back to web based gmail usage every time.

So I was wondering, what are there reasons NOT to use it, if any?

Comment: Questions about web applications are off topic on Super User - check out the FAQ

Comment: But: there's http://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq to the rescue. (If you find a similar question there, or if not and you decide to repost it there, then please leave a link here? Success!)

Comment: Well gmail techically can be used with an email client too, and it's an alternative to using one, so I thought it was "super user" enough. No complains if people want to close this, though.

Comment: And if you decide to repost: it's Gmail with a lowercase M! ;-)

Comment: kemp has reposted at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6406/why-not-to-use-gmail

Comment: Yes and voted to close this myself. Thanks to Arjan for pointing me to webapps and also for the miscapitalized 'm' :)

Answer (score 7):

It's off topic, but I'll answer anyways.  Personally I like gmail, but some concerns would include:

- No automatic offline access (you can configure it with imap or pop3, though, and this applies to all web based mail)
- No privacy.  Google actively searches all your email to advertise to you when you are logged in.
- No folders.  Some folks like folders!  I know the labels work in a similar fashion, but it's not quite the same.
- Linking to other logins.  Your google account is now used for other stuff like Youtube, OpenID, etc.  If you need to check your email on a shared PC or someone else's pc, they get logged off everything else.

Comment: Anyone care to explain their downvotes?

Comment: Not having folders is the major drawback IMHO. But i like its threading view and the keyboard navigation. Far better than thunderbirds.

Comment: I agree @MrShunz. Personally I use web-based Gmail as my primary email.  I was just playing devil's advocate here.

Comment: I guess answering off-topic questions doesn't help keeping this place from becoming Yahoo! Answers. :-(

Comment: I'm one of the downvotes. And it's -1 for **It's off topic, but I'll answer anyways.**

Comment: @Nifle - Fair enough.